# get the position of row split by comma

Tags: php, sql, position, substring, find-in-set

I have a row in my sql table that look like this

I would like to run query with find_in_set like this:

```
list
------------
1,2,5,33,3,4

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET( id, list )
```

and get the position of the result in a new field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) returns the position of the id value in the list, so:

```
SELECT *,
       FIND_IN_SET( id, list ) as position
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET( id, list )
```

or

```
SELECT *,
       FIND_IN_SET( id, list ) as position
  FROM mytable 
 HAVING position > 0
```

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php The reference for the function.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. you don't know how much time i tried to figured it out. and it so simple.

Comment: @oded, maybe if it helped, please accept it as an answer